# PL/SQL Accepting input in if else

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

This is my program:

```
SET VERIFY OFF
SET FEED OFF
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

PROMPT 'Vehicle Inventory Record'
ACCEPT p_Options;
ACCEPT myVariable PROMPT 'Input value: ';

DECLARE
  n_numb number := 1;

BEGIN

  IF '&p_Options' = 'YES' THEN        
  dbms_output.put_line('input YES');

  ELSIF '&p_Options' = 'NO' THEN    
  dbms_output.put_line('input NO');

  ELSE
  dbms_output.put_line('&myVariable');

  END IF;

END;
/
```

Now, whenever I run the program, I enter value for p_Options, but irrespective of what I enter, it asks me to input for myVariable.

I want to input value for myVariable only in the else case when p_Options is neither YES nor NO.

Why does it ask for myVariable always even when it is in the else case?

Answer (score 1):

Because substitution variables (&...) must be replaced with actual values before the procedure is interpreted, "long before" it is sent for execution.

The interpreter (as opposed to the runtime) does not evaluate the "if" statement to see if it results in true or false; that will happen at runtime.

What are you trying to do - have a procedure that prompts the user for myVariable DURING EXECUTION, and only if it is needed? You can't do that with substitution variables.

Comment: Yes, i want user to input for myVariable only if its needed. How can this be done without substitution variables?

Comment: It can't be done in PL/SQL, that is a database SERVER language, it does not interact with the end user (client side) during execution. For what you want you will need to build a front-end application, in Java or C# or whatever is used in your organization.

Comment: So, for accepting user input is there no alternative to substitution variables? Can something like SET DEFINE OFF be used in this case?

Comment: You can use bind variables. Those are used to compile your procedure, and are only needed at runtime, but BEFORE you start execution. They can't be assigned values DURING execution, as you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET VERIFY OFF

SET FEED OFF

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

PROMPT 'Vehicle Inventory Record'

ACCEPT condition;

ACCEPT myVariable PROMPT 'Input value: ';

DECLARE
  n_numb varchar2(20) := '&condition';

BEGIN

  IF n_numb = 'Y' THEN  

  dbms_output.put_line('input YES');

  ELSIF n_numb = 'N' THEN   

  dbms_output.put_line('input NO');

  ELSE
  dbms_output.put_line('NO DATA FOUND:');

  END IF;

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Its little late (and slightly different) but thought it could be useful to someone like me :)

Declare variables.
One for a condition to show a prompt.
One for storing a result if the prompt will be shown.

```
VARIABLE show_alert varchar2(10);
VARIABLE confirm varchar2(10);`
```

Now inside PLSQL block, set the show_alert value according to the requirement.
I set 'Y' for showing alert and asking a user to enter a value
'N' for not showing alert (and it won't ask for entering a value).

```
DECLARE
    r_ver   varchar2(50);
BEGIN   
    SELECT zbc
    INTO r_ver
    FROM bla_bla_table;
    IF r_ver like '12.2%' THEN
        :show_alert := 'Y';
    ELSE
        :show_alert := 'N';
    END IF; 
END;
/
```

Then I spool the accept command in cont.sql. This sql file will store accept command only if the where condition satisfies i.e. show_alert='Y' in the above block.
Then it executes the sql file using @cont.sql.

```
SPOOL cont.sql

SELECT 
    'ACCEPT confirm prompt "Continue installation (Y/N):";'
FROM
    dual
WHERE
   upper(substr(:show_alert, 1, 1)) = 'Y';

spool off
@cont.sql
```